# how to remove non duplicates in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, duplicate

How do I remove non-duplicate cells in calc?
the purpose is to delete all the rows that contain a value that exists only in one collumn.
ie:

```
A     B
1     1
2     3
3     5
5     10
7     12
8     
9
10
12
```

here the rows that contain 2,7,8,9 would be deleted

edit: I've been looking at function wizard, the answer may lie in the database category, but I don't understand most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this for the first 127 (for 500 you get Err:512) rows, move to cell C1 and paste the stuff in the bottom. Then copy C1 down to the bottom of what you want to sort.

You will then get the value `TRUE` in cell Cx if the cell Ax has a value that occurs in one or more of B1,...,B127, else `FALSE`.

Next, go to the `Data` menu, and choose `Sort...`
Under `Sort key 1`, choose column `C`. This will sort your table so all `FALSE` entries will be on top.

Then select A1 and B1, hold shift and scroll down until you reach the first `TRUE` field. Then hit delete.

You will be left with only the rows where the value in cell Ax occurs in one or more of the cells in column B.

`=OR(A1=B$1,A1=B$2,A1=B$3,A1=B$4,A1=B$5,A1=B$6,A1=B$7,A1=B$8,A1=B$9,A1=B$10,A1=B$11,A1=B$12,A1=B$13,A1=B$14,A1=B$15,A1=B$16,A1=B$17,A1=B$18,A1=B$19,A1=B$20,A1=B$21,A1=B$22,A1=B$23,A1=B$24,A1=B$25,A1=B$26,A1=B$27,A1=B$28,A1=B$29,A1=B$30,A1=B$31,A1=B$32,A1=B$33,A1=B$34,A1=B$35,A1=B$36,A1=B$37,A1=B$38,A1=B$39,A1=B$40,A1=B$41,A1=B$42,A1=B$43,A1=B$44,A1=B$45,A1=B$46,A1=B$47,A1=B$48,A1=B$49,A1=B$50,A1=B$51,A1=B$52,A1=B$53,A1=B$54,A1=B$55,A1=B$56,A1=B$57,A1=B$58,A1=B$59,A1=B$60,A1=B$61,A1=B$62,A1=B$63,A1=B$64,A1=B$65,A1=B$66,A1=B$67,A1=B$68,A1=B$69,A1=B$70,A1=B$71,A1=B$72,A1=B$73,A1=B$74,A1=B$75,A1=B$76,A1=B$77,A1=B$78,A1=B$79,A1=B$80,A1=B$81,A1=B$82,A1=B$83,A1=B$84,A1=B$85,A1=B$86,A1=B$87,A1=B$88,A1=B$89,A1=B$90,A1=B$91,A1=B$92,A1=B$93,A1=B$94,A1=B$95,A1=B$96,A1=B$97,A1=B$98,A1=B$99,A1=B$100,A1=B$101,A1=B$102,A1=B$103,A1=B$104,A1=B$105,A1=B$106,A1=B$107,A1=B$108,A1=B$109,A1=B$110,A1=B$111,A1=B$112,A1=B$113,A1=B$114,A1=B$115,A1=B$116,A1=B$117,A1=B$118,A1=B$119,A1=B$120,A1=B$121,A1=B$122,A1=B$123,A1=B$124,A1=B$125,A1=B$126,A1=B$127)`

Comment: I've edited the question again, hope is clear now. @Rasmus

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: How is that relevant? sometimes 10 sometimes 500.

Comment: Because I don't know how to make Calc quantify over the cells, testing if there exists one with same value, but the same can be obtained by a long OR statement: `=OR(A1=B$1,A1=B$2,A1=B$3,A1=B$4,...)` but that get tedious for 500 rows... With appropriate length, this would give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, that should do it, up to 500. Hooray for `=A1+1` and text editors with for multi-line editing!

Comment: you forgot to put =OR in front so I did that: =OR(A1=B$1,etc) but the cell says error:512.I figured the dollar sign should be there so I deleted it from the first rows and it worked, but only for the first (A1) when I copied C1 to the bottom it automatically increased +1 on all numbers. not just on the A ones.

Comment: Err:512 results from too long an expression, I guess. It cuts it at 127, so so did I. Then it seems to work (on a short test list). Keep the $, it makes it not change the value during paste.

Comment: YES! I tried to edit one small thing: Its =OR(A... instead of OR=(A... @Rasmus

Comment: Super! It's corrected!